# How To Change Color Workspace in Adobe Dreamweaver Cs5?

Tags: dreamweaver

i useing as adobe dreamweaver ; i will change color the workspace (environment code editor)
 for ex: I want to be black environment code;
thanks;
sorry for english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the Skin color of Dreamweaver. You can't. Check out the website here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7f82a.html#WS8599BC5C-3E44-406c-9288-C3B3BBEB5E88

Note (From Adobe.com): The user interface has been simplified in Dreamweaver CC and later. As a result, you may not find some of the options described in this article in Dreamweaver CC and later. For more information, see this article.

Answer (score 0):

You can change colors in Edit -> Preferences -> Code Coloring

or

http://sramekdesign.com/dreamweaver/dark-coding-colorization-for-dreamweaver/

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are using a macbook,

Command+U

to open the dialog box for Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no option to darken the UI, but there it is a feature request.
Please vote for the request here: https://forums.adobe.com/ideas/3824 so we might expect this functionality in the future, so we could save our eyes a bit ;)